# how to add html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, append, innerhtml

i have some simple jquery code which im using to create [this page](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/programs.html) dynamically instead of manually. here is my code

loop

```
for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    $("#programs").append(
        $("li")
        .html("div")
        .html("a", {
            href: links[i] + ".exe"
        })
        .html("img", {
            src: icons[i]
        })
        .html("p")
        .html(captions[i])
    );
}
```

declarations of arrays

```
var links = ["pictureVeiwer","maze","firefoxPrank"];

var icons = ["firefox-icon.gif","maze.jpg","imageVeiwer.jpg"];

var captions = ["Cute Firfox prank","Cool maze","Program to veiw pictures... kinda useless in 2013"];
```

I assume my syntax is a bit off, I have used similar code before but not in a loop. What am I doing wrong and how should I do this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/zwhgw/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working here. A little verbose, but also clearer:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    // Each list item will contain a div
    var $li = $("<li/>")

    // Each div will have a link, and that link will have an image and a caption
    var $div = $("<div/>");

    // Give the link its image
    var $a = $("<a/>", {
        href: links[i] + ".exe"
    });
    var $img = $("<img/>", {
        src: icons[i]
    });
    $a.append($img);

    // Give the link its caption
    $p = $("<p/>");
    $p.html(captions[i]);
    $a.append($p);

    // Give the div its link
    $div.append($a);

    // Give the list item its div
    $li.append($div);

    // Add the list item to the list
    $("#programs").append($li);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/zwhgw/8/)
(You will need to try it on your own site, where your images can be referenced.)

Comment: output is this `<li>
<div>
<a href="firefoxPrank.exe">
<img>
</a>
<p>Program to veiw pictures... kinda useless in 2013</p>
</div>
</li>` (1) `p`  outside of `a` (2) no `src` in `img`

Comment: fixed problem (1) - http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/zwhgw/6/ i will accept if you can fix the `src` problem as well

Comment: found and fixed (2) - http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/zwhgw/8/ - missing `$(` before `img` (and a closing `)`)

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. Glad you caught it. I'll fix my answer for the future generations.

Comment: Revision 8 (http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/zwhgw/8/) looks like it would work. Is something not working on http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/programs.html?

Comment: no its working you just didnt edit it in to your answer (im using it atm - http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/programs.html)

Comment: Ah, I missed the "`<p>` in the `<a>`" part. Got it now.

Answer (score 2):

`$("li")` selects all the `li` elements on the page, actually you don't create new elements, it should be:

```
$("<li/>");
```

or:

```
$("<li></li>");
```

Also you are chaining `.html()` methods which overwrites previous contents, I would suggest creating elements separately, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var $li = $("<li/>"),
        $a = $("<a/>", { href: links[i] + ".exe", text: 'whatever' }),
        $img = $('<img/>', { src: icons[i] });
        $div = $('<div/>').append($a).append($img);

    $li.append($div).appendTo('#programs');  
      // |          |
      // |          ---- append the `li` element to #programs            
      // |           
      // ---- append to the `li` element
}
```

If you are generating many elements dynamically you can consider using a templating library like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/).

Comment: thanks for the help so far but i still get this - http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/zwhgw/3/ - it adds the html **outside** the elements

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight `.append()` methods doesn't return the appended element, it returns the current collection, that's why I have suggested creating the elements separately, what are you currently is doing is writing spaghetti-like/unmanageable code (sorry) which produces unexpected results.

Comment: can you write it with a "img" in there?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use templating, like Underscore provides:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-template">
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="<%= href %>"><img src="<%= src %>"></a>
            <p><%= caption %></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>

<ul id="programs"></ul>

<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var $programsList = $('#programs');
var listTemplateHtml = $('#list-template').html();
for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1 ) {
    var li = _.template(listTemplateHtml, {
        href: links[i] + ".exe",
        src: icons[i],
        captions: captions[i]
    });
    $programsList.append(li);
}
```

This would be much easier and more maintainable, and probably yield better performance, too.